# What‘s the action command name of Goland "go to interface" in ideavim

Tags: goland, ideavim

I'm using Ideavim in Goland, and I trying to configure the key mapping in `.ideavimrc`. I searched the Ideavim ActionList on web, and did not find a command name for "go to interface". Run `:action GotoInterface` or `:action GotoInterfaces` also shows that no command call this。

Does anyone know that? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:action GotoSuperMethod` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

IdeaVIM has a feature to display action IDs as you do things. See the section [Finding action ids](https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim#executing-ide-actions) in the IdeaVim README for details on how to use that.

If for some reason that doesn't work, I've come up with another way to find action names to use in IdeaVIM key bindings (or anywhere else you need the action name). Here is the process:

1. Go to IntelliJ settings and open the Keymap settings.
2. Use the search bar to find the action.
3. Right-click (or ⌃-click) on the action and choose "Add Abbreviation".
4. Type in a string that's unlikely to be used anywhere else. I use "zjzjzj".
5. Click OK to close settings and save to disk.
6. Open up your IntelliJ Configuration directory. This is `idea.config.path` on the page [Directories used by the IDE to store settings, caches, plugins and logs](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs). Currently on my machine it is "~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2023.2" but it depends on your OS and IntelliJ version.
7. Open up the file `options/abbrevs.xml` in a text editor.
8. Search for the string you used in Step 4, e.g. "zjzjzj".
9. Now you'll see the action id you're looking for. Example below.
10. Clean up by removing the abbreviation in Settings→Keymap.

Example of what shows up in abbrevs.xml:

```xml
      <action id="GotoSuperMethod">
        <abbreviation name="zjzjzj" />
      </action>
```